# Cant change column axis alignment inside a SingChildScroll view

Tags: flutter, dart, alignment, singlechildscrollview

i wanna add spacing between my widgets inside the column without hard coding every SizedBox and give them certain heights, i want to set it directly on the column but none of the alignment options work, what am i doing wrong? whats causing this?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Submit Your Order'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround, // doesnt work
              children: [
                InformationField(
                  label: 'Phone Number',
                  hintText: 'Type Your Phone Number',
                ),
                InformationField(
                  label: 'Name',
                  hintText: 'Type Your Name',
                ),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    InformationField(
                      label: 'Adress',
                      hintText: 'Neighborhood/City',
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5.0,
                    ),
                    RowInformationField()
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `SingleChildScrollView` don't expect `mainAxisAlignment` to work. I'd suggest you to replace it with `CustomScrollView` to achieve your desired results.